# VBA - Duplicate worksheets and rename, skip blank cells

Tags: vba

I'm duplicating worksheets, and renaming from a list. The list includes non-zero values - which is creating an issue. How do I skip over the blank cells?

```
Sub AddSheet()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate
    Dim bottomA As Integer
    bottomA = Range("L" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Dim c As Range
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    For Each c In Range("L5:L" & bottomA)
       Set ws = Nothing
       On Error Resume Next
       Set ws = Worksheets(c.Value)
       On Error GoTo 0
       If ws Is Nothing Then
           Sheets("LBO").Select
           Sheets("LBO").Copy After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
           ActiveSheet.Name = c.Value
       End If
    Next c   
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You should just include an additional condition within your `If` statement.

For example, to avoid when there is an empty cell:

`If ws Is Nothing And Len(c) > 0 Then`